# Bootstrap 4 Responsive table with column width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have a bootstrap 4 responsive table. and I have this look on pc.
[image: On THE PC]
and the code is

```
<table class="table table-bordered m-table m-table--border-metal m-table--head-bg-primary" style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%;">
    <!--begin::Thead-->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="3%">#</th>
            <th width="15%">Name</th>
            <th width="8%">Ref. Code</th>
            <th width="3%">Pax</th>
            <th width="8%">Tour dates</th>
            <th width="10%">Type</th>
            <th width="10%">Email</th>
            <th width="8%">Country</th>
            <th width="7%">Language</th>
            <th width="7%">Status</th>
            <th width="21%">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!--end::Thead-->
    <!--begin::Tbody-->
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>23</td>
                <td style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;" title="Name Sirname">NAME SİRNAME</td>
                <td>SLPT0419CAR</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2019-04-19</td>
                <td>manual</td>
                <td style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;" title="name2@hotmail.com">name2@hotmail.com</td>
                <td>Colombia</td>
                <td>Spanish</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="la la-eye"></i> Details</button></a> &nbsp;
                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="la la-pencil"></i>Edit</button></i></a> &nbsp;
                    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="delete_request(23)"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="la la-trash"></i>Delete</button></a>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>19</td>
                <td style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;" title="name sirname">Name Sirname</td>
                <td>SLPT0419CARL</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2019-04-19</td>
                <td>manual</td>
                <td style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;" title="name2004@yahoo.com">name2004@yahoo.com</td>
                <td>Uruguay</td>
                <td>Spanish</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="la la-eye"></i> Details</button></a> &nbsp;
                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="la la-pencil"></i>Edit</button></i></a> &nbsp;
                    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="delete_request(19)"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="la la-trash"></i>Delete</button></a>
                </td>

            </tr>                  
    </tbody>
    <!--end::Tbody-->                                           
</table>
<!--end::Table-->
```

On mobile I got this view

[image: MObile1]

When I change table class to auto

style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%;"

This time I got on pc

[image: PC2]
and on mobile works as it should be. Which is good.

[image: Mobile2]

First one is good for the pc and second one is good for the mobile.

How can i get work in both environment?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. You shouldn't use percentage width in table headers but a scope attribute.

```
<table class="table table-bordered m-table m-table--border-metal m-table--head-bg-primary">
    <!--begin::Thead-->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th  scope="col" >#</th>
            <th  scope="col" >Name</th>
            <th  scope="col" >Ref. Code</th>
            <th  scope="col" >Pax</th>
            <th   scope="col">Tour dates</th>
            <th  scope="col">Type</th>
            <th  scope="col">Email</th>
            <th  scope="col">Country</th>
            <th  scope="col">Language</th>
            <th  scope="col">Status</th>
            <th  scope="col">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!--end::Thead-->
    <!--begin::Tbody-->
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th >23</th>
                <td style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;" title="Name Sirname">NAME SİRNAME</td>
                <td>SLPT0419CAR</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2019-04-19</td>
                <td>manual</td>
                <td style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;" title="name2@hotmail.com">name2@hotmail.com</td>
                <td>Colombia</td>
                <td>Spanish</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="la la-eye"></i> Details</button></a> &nbsp;
                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="la la-pencil"></i>Edit</button></i></a> &nbsp;
                    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="delete_request(23)"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="la la-trash"></i>Delete</button></a>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>19</th>
                <td style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;" title="name sirname">Name Sirname</td>
                <td>SLPT0419CARL</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2019-04-19</td>
                <td>manual</td>
                <td style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;" title="name2004@yahoo.com">name2004@yahoo.com</td>
                <td>Uruguay</td>
                <td>Spanish</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="la la-eye"></i> Details</button></a> &nbsp;
                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="la la-pencil"></i>Edit</button></i></a> &nbsp;
                    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="delete_request(19)"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="la la-trash"></i>Delete</button></a>
                </td>

            </tr>                  
    </tbody>
    <!--end::Tbody-->                                           
</table>
<!--end::Table-->
```

Comment: I try it on pc in various resolutions and there isn't a problem.Then what is the expected looking?

Comment: I would say you can see PC2 image but On my side image links doesnt open. Image links are working or not?